# You don't have permission to acces /phpmyadmin on this server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

Tengo un servidor montado en una maquina centos 7 y un dns dinamico al que puedo acceder de manera remota, pero cuando intento entrar a la base de datos que tengo en ese server mediante php my admin, me sale esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busque en internet y le que tengo que modificar el archivo /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf 
lo modifique segun las paginas que visite, pero no se como modificarlo para que pueda acceder al phpmyadmin de mi servidor.

**Este es el codigo que tengo en phpMyAdmin.conf**

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from none
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from none
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from All
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: Si tu pregunta fue resulta por tu respuesta. Marcala como resuelta , para que otros con el mismo problema puedan ver la solucion

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo he resuelto, para los que necesiten ayuda en este problema, si les sirve, mi solución consistió en.

```
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
```

Comentar Require ip 127.0.01 y Require ::1 y añadir en la linea de abajo Require all granted para que al final quede así.

```
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
```

Después de modificar esas lineas, guardamos el archivo y reiniciamos el servicio httpd

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Y listo, todo solucionado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no me funciono.
no que que problema tengo sigue saliéndome así:....! Prohibido
No tiene permiso para acceder a / phpmyadmin en este servidor.